# Return URL list for a Google Search

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Was wondering what the easiest way to return a list/array of URLs from a google search result. I would be using JS and the Google API

What i want to do it this

Google a term like "dogs"

Have a array/list of URLs that are relevant to that search:
domainurl1
domainurl2

etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
options[google.search.Search.RESTRICT_EXTENDED_ARGS] = {
  'cr': 'countryIT',
  'sort': 'date'
};
var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(id, options);
```

Here is the syntax to get Return url list

```
google.search.CustomSearchControl.CustomSearch
      Control(cseId, opt_options);
```

You will get proper details in this link : [Return URL list](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference)